# How to count occurrence 2 words at random places in a line in UNIX

Tags: unix, count, words

Example (the file has following text):

```
tom is really really cool!  joe for the win!
tom is actually smart.
tom and joe are best buddies. Joe is smart.
joe works hard
```

Now i want to find no of lines in this file that has joe and tom used in single line using `UNIX`. 
so the answer should be 2 (ie first and forth lines only)

Comment: `joe` and `tom` are used in a single line, in lines 1 and 3 and not 4.

Comment: Since you are pretty new here, see [When a user receives a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: The answer is simple: construct a DFA https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton (this is exactly what grep does, internally) In your case you could even construct it by hand, there are only two patterns that share only one letter, and they do not overlap.

Answer (score 1):

You can use plain `grep` with `-c` flag for counting the instances. For your input `file`,

```
grep 'tom.*joe\|joe.*tom' file
tom is really really cool!  joe for the win!
tom and joe are best buddies. Joe is smart.

grep -c 'tom.*joe\|joe.*tom' file
2
```

Comment: I was writing such a long program. :( grep is so powerful!